# How to add header html to VF page

Tags: html, salesforce, visualforce, apex

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false">
</head>
<body>
<div>
Header html should load here 
</div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

I have a html file with some heading html codes. 'header.html' how to include this file to my VF page as dynamic header?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce store your HTML file inside the database as metadata, so this means that it can be queried for.

You'll need a controller extension for your `<apex:page>`. Check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) on how to do that.

So, your controller will have a method like so:

```
public string getHeaderHtml() {
        try {
            return [Select Body From Document Where Id = 'YOUR_PAGE_ID'].Body.toString();

        } catch(exception e) {
            return '';
        }
    }
```

And in your Visualforce page you'll have this line where you want your HeaderHtml to be placed:

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!HeaderHtml}"/>
```

OR

Alternative option is to use `<apex:iframe>` with it's `src` pointing to your header file url like `src="/apex/MyPage"`. Check the documentation [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_iframe.htm).

Comment: Thanks For ur Ans. I could create vf component for header &  called  it to all pages.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem please mark it as `answer` so others facing the same issue can see it. Thank you!